# How can the month reputation be greater than the actual days in month * daily limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

The [monthly Stack Overflow league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) shows x users having gained more than 2800 reputation points so far this month.

As we are the 14th of April, how can a user gain more than 2800 (14 days * 200 reputation points limit)?

Comment: Bounties and accepted answers, mostly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While upvotes can give you a max reputation of 200, *accepted answers* (+15) and *bounties* (+X) are not limited.

For example, if you have 30 upvotes, 5 accepted answers and awarded a bounty of 50, your reputation will be:

```
(20 * 10) + (5 * 15) + 50 = 325
```